# What is the best way to get a list of events from multiple facebook accounts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I currently have something working that does this but the way I got it working requires me to update my access token every ~2 months, which is less than ideal.  I feel like there must be a better way.

I do not want to add/remove/modify events at all (read only).

I simply want to get any upcoming events from a predetermined group of users/pages. So I currently just loop through my list of users/pages and make a request to the graph API for each one.

This is the endpoint that I am using:

```
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/${vendor.fb_id}/events?fields=description%2Cstart_time%2Cend_time%2Ccover%2Cname%2Cowner&since=${date}&access_token=${config.fb_token}`
```

Comment: so...those events are user events, right?

Comment: @luschn yes.  I do not need to add/remove/modify them though.  I simply want to get any upcoming events from a predetermined group of users/pages.  So I currently just loop through my list of users/pages and make a request to the graph API for each one.

Answer (score 1):

Extended User Tokens are valid for 2 months, i assume that is what you are using. There is no way to circumvent that without user interaction, i´m afraid.

For Pages, you can just use an App Token or an Extended Page Token. Both are valid forever, but you can only use an App Token if the Page is not restricted by age or location.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. :(

I was just hoping since what I need is read only that there might be another way.

Comment: no, there is not, i´m afraid. userdata needs a user token, and it can only be valid for 2 months max.